# Sony Vaio Blackout Display Issue

Tags: sony-vaio, blank-screen

Symptoms:

1. Since two weeks display used to suddenly disappear and then when it comes back the brightness used to be 100% scaled automatically.
2. Now the computer is booting, the fan's voice is there, Keyboards caps Lock is showing LED ON/OFF, but permanent blackout.
3. Sony Vaio Blackout Display Issues, screen/monitor tested today by replacing with 3 new display screens and seems to be not working that means my original may also be right, what else could be the culprit?

I took the machine to the local vendor he tried to troubleshoot the initially blamed the screen, but he tested with 3 screens none worked, which means the issue is somewhere from the motherboard.

Which steps should I take now? which hardware components should I suspect?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Done, Two categories deleted. Thanks.

Comment: Title also updated to be more informative.